# Understanding 自由席ならあります

Tags: conditionals

Consider

> いいえ、売り切れましたが、自由席ならあります。
>
> No, they are sold out, but we have unreserved seats.

**Questions:**

1. 自由席 breaks down into "self-reason-seat" Kanji-wise.  Does anyone know why this converts into a meaning of "unreserved seat"?  (Maybe something like: "the *reason* of *myself* being here justifies that this *seat* is mine")?
2. The phrase "自由席ならあります" literally means something like "if it's an unreserved seat, it exists", correct? (More idiomatically: "if it's an unreserved seat [you want], it's [here for you]").

Comment: Do you know 自由 means free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [自由](https://jisho.org/search/%E8%87%AA%E7%94%B1) is a common word that means *free(dom)* or *liberty*. 自由席 means a seat anyone can take *freely* without a reservation. The history of the word 自由 itself is explained in [this section](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%87%AA%E7%94%B1#%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E8%A8%B3) of Japanese Wikipedia (basically it's a [wasei-kango](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasei-kango) coined to translate English *liberty*). I think "self-reasoning" is not too far from the idea of liberty.
2. Yes. This type of なら is very common.